# Oracle local database product (like MS Access)

Tags: software-rec, database, sql

Is there a Oracle, local database product (which I can run on my laptop like MS Access) which is free for developers, and in which I can Create tables, Load data from file, Run SQL (oracle's syntax) using Toad.
Basically a local sandbox for me to try out stuff without worrying about network or admin.

Comment: Oracle Express Edition?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/overview/index.html

I don't know if this needs administrative rights to install locally.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I was looking for!, you can make it as your answer, Thanks Cloneman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Express Edition? 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/overview/index.html

I don't know if this needs administrative rights to install locally.